# How to hide the data in between the two tags(<hidden> ...... </hidden>) in Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

Need a code such that... the data what ever present between two tags should be hidden.. for that sake what i did is firstly i searched for  tagin the document and i replaced that tag with the registered symbol(®) and get the range like that . i need a code in a way without replacing the tag

```
Sub Test()
Dim i As Long
i = 0
Dim myWord As String
myWord = "®"
TargetList = Array("</hidden>")
With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
     .Text = "</hidden>"
     .Replacement.Text = myWord
     .Wrap = wdFindContinue
     .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With 
  Counter = 1
Set Range = ActiveDocument.Range
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
With Selection.Find
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Text = "<hidden>"
While .Execute
    Counter = Counter + 1
Wend
End With
For i = 0 To Counter
Set Range = ActiveDocument.Range
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
With Selection.Find
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Text = "<hidden>"
If .Execute(Forward:=True) = True Then
With Selection.Range
Selection.MoveEndUntil Cset:="®", Count:=wdForward
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.Font.Hidden = True
End With
End If
End With
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: How does this question relate to Java?

Comment: Yes... But i am finding solution in both Java and VBA(macro)

Here what i need is i dont want to replace the the </hidden> with special character...

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you need help with your VBA code?

Comment: We cannot help you with you explaining clearly what is wrong with the code you posted. Your question is likely to be closed unless you become a lot more descriptive.

Comment: **suppose the document is like tis :**
<hidden> This is Krishna… this should be Hide </hidden>

This is Krishna….this should be Shown

This is Krishna….this should be Shown <hidden> This is Krishna….this should be Hide </hidden>

I need a code such that... the data what ever present between two tags(<hidden>......</hidden>) should be hidden.. for that sake what i did is firstly i searched for </hidden> tagin the document and i replaced that tag with the registered symbol(®) and get the range like that (<hidden>......®). 

i need a code in a way without **replacing** the tag

Comment: pls check by :

1> prepare a word document as i stated 
( <hidden> This is Krishna… this should be Hide </hidden>
 This is Krishna….this should be Shown 
This is Krishna….this should be Shown <hidden> This is Krishna….this should be Hide </hidden>)
2> Hide the data including the tags (Follow :Select the data,Rightclick,font,Hidden)
3> Now the data will be hidden(data is present in doc but hidden)
4> To check the data, we can use the Show/Hidden data in the word toolbar

i need the VBA to be like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using a simple Word Find and Replace using wild cards:

```
With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .ClearAllFuzzyOptions

    .text = "[<]hidden[>](*)[<]/hidden[>]"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = True

    .Replacement.text = ""
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting

    .Replacement.Font.Hidden = True

    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
```

if you want to remove the tags as well, use the following replacement text:

```
    .Replacement.text = "\1"
```

Comment: Thanks oxA3, Its working amazing... Full filled my need... Pls can u help in developing  the same using java code

Comment: @oxA3: You mistook me,but i would have been specific. I have been working the same for generating using JAVA, IN specific able to Read the input document using Apache POI and also able to find the data between the tags(What to be hidden) but the problem is i'm unable to write the data in the output file. How can i do the same to write the data and hide it in the output generated file

Comment: @oxA3: http://bytes.com/topic/java/answers/949438-how-hide-data-between-two-tags-hidden-hidden-word-document#post3749993 

check the funtionality i have done